# Why can't I get the extra that I put on my main activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have put extra with this code on my main activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(ItemMainActivity.this, (Class<?>) map.get("itemActivity"));
intent.putExtra("user",user);
intent.putExtra("userID",userID);
startActivity(intent);
```

When I try to get the extra by using this code, it returns null:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String user = null, userID = null;
if (extras != null) {
    user = extras.getString("user");
    userID = extras.getString("userID");
}
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"user: "+user+" id: "+userID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: That should work.  Are you sure it's the right instance and that you aren't setting it to null?  Please give a [mre] that defines `user` and `userID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest another way.... The concept of a common class.
And make a public static variable of the data type which you need and set the value in the activity and access it wherever you need.

```
Public class Common{
    Public static String userId ="";
      }
```

Set value in this variable `Common.userId  = "YOUR_VALUE"`
**When need to access just use** `Common.userId`

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.**

Comment: It workss thank you, i made it like this : 

1. i put extras when logged in 
2. get extras in the main activity 
3. i made new class as session that get the extras from my main activity

Is it bad ? thank you for your help..

Comment: This is dangerous, because if the system kills the app in the background, that won't be set, while an extra would be.  You'll have subtle crashes that only happen when the user is switching between apps.